Scheduled function sometimes throws error when using sendToTopic
I've implemented a scheduled function in Firebase (1st generation) that runs every 5 minutes. The code snippet below is a simplified version of the function, which shows just the problematic part:
initializeApp()

export const example = runWith({
  timeoutSeconds: 20,
  memory: '128MB',
  maxInstances: 1,
  minInstances: 0,
})
  .region('europe-west1')
  .pubsub.schedule('*/5 * * * *')
  .onRun(async () => {
    const date = new Date();

    const weekday = date.getDay();
    const hour = date.getHours();
    const minute = Math.floor(date.getMinutes() / 15) * 15;

    const topicName = `${weekday}-${hour}-${minute}`;

    const messaging = getMessaging();

    try {
      await messaging.sendToTopic(
        topicName,
        {
          data: {
            mode: '15MinSchedule',
            type: topicName,
          },
        },
        {
          priority: 'high',
        },
      );
      debug(`Successfully sent to topic: ${topicName}`);
    } catch (err) {
      warn(`Error sending to topic ${topicName}:`, err);
    }
  });

The issue occurs intermittently, approximately every 2 to 3 hours, when the sendToTopic method throws the following error (the full log is provided at the end of this post):
"error":"Deprecated endpoint, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1"

Based on the error message, it appears that the function is attempting to access a deprecated FCM-endpoint (v1). I'm not sure, but I think the firebase-admin package should already be using the correct, non-deprecated endpoint without requiring any manual migration, right?
However, most of the time everything works fine and as I said, it just throws the error around once every 2 hours, after which it sends the messages correctly again.
What I have already tried

Deleted the build, package-lock.json and node_modules directory and redeployed the function
Deleted schedule-function in google-cloud and redeployed the function

Package version:
"firebase-admin": "^12.3.1",
"firebase-functions": "^5.0.1",

Error log:
{
  "textPayload": "FirebaseMessagingError: An unknown server error was returned. Raw server response: \"{\"error\":\"Deprecated endpoint, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1\"}\"\n    at FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:269:16)\n    at createFirebaseError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-errors-internal.js:35:47)\n    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request-internal.js:80:75\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async sendToTopic (/workspace/lib/scheduled/***.js:73:9)\n    at async Promise.all (index 1)\n    at async exports.default (/workspace/lib/scheduled/***.js:43:5)\n    at async /workspace/lib/group-functions/pubsub-group.js:56:5 {\n  errorInfo: {\n    code: 'messaging/unknown-error',\n    message: 'An unknown server error was returned. Raw server response: \"{\"error\":\"Deprecated endpoint, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1\"}\"'\n  },\n  codePrefix: 'messaging'\n}",
  "insertId": "66cdb534000ecdfcc85c9c9e",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "pubsub-min5Schedule",
      "region": "europe-west1",
      "project_id": "***"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-08-27T11:15:00.970236Z",
  "severity": "WARNING",
  "labels": {
    "runtime_version": "nodejs20_20240818_20_16_0_RC00",
    "execution_id": "***",
    "instance_id": "***"
  },
  "logName": "projects/***/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/***/traces/cee5cfbbaf474cae746709dafadd9785",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-08-27T11:15:00.995052585Z"
}


If you think firebase-admin isn't doing the right thing, you should file an issue on GitHub with your steps to reproduce the issue.  If the documentation is silent on the issue, Stack Overflow can't really help.

I found the solution by myself:
As of August 22, 2024, the sendToTopic and sendToCondition methods have been deprecated, and we now need to use send for both. I've run this for a day, and everything is working smoothly without any issues.

thanyou bro  .... you saved my life
